# accessing model with socket.io causes namespace error in backbone view

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, namespaces, socket.io

I have a question about using sockets in a backbone view.

How do I access the model from inside of a socket listener? I want to do something like...

> window.SocketView = Backbone.View.extend({
>
> ```
> initialize:function () {
>
>      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'updateModelFromServer'); 
>
>     this.render();
>
> },
>
> render:function () {
>     $(this.el).html(this.template());
>     return this;
> },
>
> events: {
>
>     "click #chageGlobalState"       : "updateModelFromServer"
> },
>
> updateModelFromServer: function() {
>
>    socket.emit("globalState", 1);
>
>    socket.on("updateState", function(data) {
>
>         this.model.set("state", data);
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> });

this results in a socket.io namespace error. 
What is the best way to share data between sockets and models?

Is there a simple syntax issue I am missing?

or do I need to dive deeper and use ...

an event aggregator? Backbone.ioBind? Marionette? dnode?

This project is a multimedia chat-like web application.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the wrong `this` inside your socket callback.

Instead of doing this:

```
socket.on("updateState", function(data) {
    this.model.set("state", data);
});
```

Try doing this:

```
socket.on("updateState", function(data) {
    this.model.set("state", data);
}.bind(this));
```